# Is it uncommon, at this point, not to have heard back from a PhD program that I interviewed with?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I interviewed with a program about 1.5 months ago and I have not heard anything back from them, and I am starting to worry a little. (US student/domestic application)

Comment: Did they give you a time frame as to when you'll hear back from them?

Comment: Maybe. In my country, the process could take a few months.

Comment: They did not give me a time frame.

Comment: Most graduate schools in the US abide by the shared April 15 guideline, and so try to get out all offers much earlier: http://cgsnet.org/april-15-resolution However, on TheGradCafe there are hundreds of results still being posted per day: https://thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php It's certainly reasonable to check up on your application after the first week of April, because it's awfully late in the usual season for most programs.

Answer (score 2):

You should send a thank and then do a follow-up. It's a job you are trying to get in a bad economy. Get that job! Be scrappy and show you are the most professional and have follow through. Compliment them on the honor to have been selected for interview with such a reputable and acomplished person, institution, etc. Tell them you looked further into their research and interests and would consider it an honor to learn from them. Play ball, get in the game or someone else will!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't hurt to ask. But first make your best to make sure you are informed about the timeline of the scholarship. This includes when they should send out the selection results.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say follow up via email, requesting information about the status of your candidature. If you don't get a reply in a day or two, try calling them on phone. It's your career so you have a right to know about this. It might even be seen as keenness to join, in case they are undecided.